# Configuration system failed to initialize (user.config) after power failure or improper shutdown

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, configuration, settings

I realize that there are a few topics on SO with almost the same title, although there is non that describes the behavior some of my users experience.

Using the build in settings of visual studio with all settings set to "User Scope"

> The next exception will turn up, only and typically when there is an improper  computer shutdown (when someone turns off computer without shutting down Windows).
>
> Power failure is also another possible cause.

Settings are loaded at startup and saved on form close.

**Exception snippet:**

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\APPLICATIONNAME.exe_Url_dbamatfk4dvaz3ykr4crkwlnzkz0kr4g\1.12.2.1\user.config line 1) ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

This can only be fixed with deleting the `user.config` file (in above mentioned folder), as the file seems to be corrupted and restart the application (the user settings will rebuilt at this time). All settings are defaulted again at this stage.

**Question:**

Why does the config file gets corrupted when there is a power failure or wrong system shutdown ?

Any way I can prevent this from happening ?

Comment: NTFS is a journaling file system, designed to prevent this kind of corruption.  But in the past fat year to so, I've seen lots of questions from programmers that were saving a source file, got a power-outage and found the file back filled with zeros.  Something is messing this up, high odds that it is anti-malware.

Comment: @HansPassant that is very unpleasant, each time those users get a power outage they loose there settings (at least when the application is running).